# How to overwrite csv columns after doing operations on them?

Tags: python, csv

I have a few csv files, each has 3 columns. I would like to compare the third columns with a value and if it's bigger than that value, subtract the value from that element and overwrite the results to the existing csvs third columns.

I don't want to alter the first two columns. So far I've done this:

```
import csv
import os
value = 10

with open('1new.csv', 'w') as outp, open('1.csv', 'r') as inp:
writer = csv.writer(outp, delimiter=',')
for row in csv.reader(inp):
    if int(row[2]) > value:
        row[2] = int(row[2]) - value
    else:
        row[2] = row[2]
    writer.writerow(int(row[2])
os.rename('1new.csv', '1.csv')
```

after printing row[2] I know the subtracting works OK, but I can't overwrite the columns and I want to know how to do the overwriting for multiple csv files instead of manually renaming the input files. This is my first time working with python and csv files and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening two files, you just need to operate on one, but just separate the "reading from file" block and "writing to file" block.

```
import csv

value = 10

with open('001.csv', 'r') as inp:
    data = list(csv.reader(inp))  # converting to list for easy modification

for row in data:
    if int(row[2]) > value:
        row[2] = int(row[2]) - value
    else:
        row[2] = row[2]

with open('001.csv', 'w') as outp:
    writer = csv.writer(outp)
    writer.writerows(data)    # note writerows() method for multiple row entry from an iterable like list
```

This won't create new file, and will overwrite on existing file.

But note: this doesn't actually overwrite a column, instead it will overwrite the whole file.

Such are more conveniently done with a package called `pandas` in python, which can save many lines of code.

Comment: This does the overwriting job but it makes an empty row between every two rows.

Comment: does it delete a row , or just leaves an empty space

Comment: It doubles the number of rows and adds an empty row for rows with an even index!

Comment: could you include a few lines from your original csv in your question?

Comment: there was a parenthesis typo in my answer,fixed it. but I ran my code on the sample csv you provided, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: adding newline=' ' to open solved the problem.

Comment: great!. I couldn't explain why does that help you. Like I said my code was working properly for the sample csv you provided. May be our execution methods were different.

Answer (score 0):

you can firstly read the file and store the modified content of file in temp list and then you can save this list in the existing file. so that it will override the original content with modified content. hava a look at code.

```
import csv
import os
value = 10

temp=[] 

with open('001new.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if int(row[2]) > value:
            row[2] = int(row[2]) - value
        else:
            row[2] = row[2]
        temp.append(row)

with open('001new.csv', mode='w') as outp:
    writer = csv.writer(outp, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(temp)
```